# static code analysis for assembly language

Tags: assembly, code-analysis, static-analysis, machine-code

Are there any open-source tools or libraries for static code analysis of simple custom assembly-like languages (for automatically generated programs) and what are they capable of (detecting unused code/registers, giving high-level expressions for code segments, call graphs etc.)? Which algorithms do exist in this field?

Comment: *Custom* assembly codes?  Are these variants of well-known instructions sets (e.g., PowerPC or x86) or are they really custom?
If they are really custom, you need a way to define the instruction set and semantics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a link that has been sitting in my bookmarks for a while: I have meant to take a deeper look at it but I never found the time to: [Vine/Bitblaze](http://bitblaze.cs.berkeley.edu/vine.html).

Comment: Is there a modern x64 assembly static code analyzer for Windows?